# Display array to look like below

Tags: angularjs

```
var $scope.data = [
{
   id: 1,
   name: "Akash"
},
{
   id: 2,
   name: "Vipul"
},
{
   id: 3,
   name: "Mahesh"
}];
var character = [];       
_.filter($scope.data, function (item) {
   character.push(item.id);
});
console.log("Character::", character);
```

Output:: Character:: ["1", "2", "3"]

I want output like:

**You character is 1, 2, and 3.**

Comment: Show your code you tried for this.

Comment: sir i think you forgot to mention submission date for us. please mention it, then we will do your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below

```
char [] data = { 'C', 'c', 'b', 'B', 'A' };
string joinString = string.Join( ", ", data );

string result = string.Format( "your character is {0}", joinString.Insert( joinString.LastIndexOf(",")+1, " and") );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [ "C", "c", "b", "B", "A" ];
var text ="";
arr.forEach(function(val,index){
  if(index <= arr.length-2){
    text = text +  val +","
  }else{
    text = text +" and " +val
  }

  
})
console.log("Your characters are",text)
```